# ESXi 6.7u2 DL380 GEN9 Hosts keep going unresponsive

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

We have recently upgraded to ESXi6.7 u2. Since the upgrade, our hosts keep going into an 'unresponsive' state. The VM's are all still running, although they show as 'disconnected' in VSphere. Can ping the host and the VM's fine.

If I log onto the ESXi console and hit F2 to open the menu, it takes several minutes to actually switch the screen, and selecting an option in there takes forever.

Until today I have been resetting the host to get it back online. However I have now been able to resurrect the host be restarting the management services (./sbin/services.sh restart) has brought it back online.

I have seen some detail online about SIO causing this issue, but none of our datastores use SIO.

Has anyone come across this before? We have an open ticket with VMWare support but they are not being particularly quick about it.

Answer (score 0):

First go hpe site and download the last spp version and update your server after that find esxi 6.7 custom for hp server and upgrade your esxi i tink your problem have been solved